# How can I set up Django Crontab in Docker container?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cron, django-rest-framework

Let's assume that I would like to run custom management command in Django every day at 12 noon. Server is deployed on Heroku in Docker container. I have in `management/commands` file `myfile.py` and I set it up in this way

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* 12 * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['myfile']),
]
```

I added `django-crontab` to the `requirements.txt` and `'django_crontab'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. This file should add data to the PostgreSQL database however it doesn't work. Any ideas how can I do that? It seems to me that there is a problem with Docker. Maybe I should use Celery scheduler instead?

**UPDATE**
I solved my problem using [Heroku APScheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python). But If anyone knows how this can be resolved for instance with celery or crontab I would be grateful for the answer.

Comment: read about python-clerey

Comment: The cron deamon is not running in the container. You could run the cron jobs in a different container from the web server, but using the same image.

Comment: @HåkenLid So it would be better to use Celery? Or maybe it also will not be working with Docker?

Comment: cron is a simpler solution than celery. So it's not better unless you need the extra features provided by celery.

Comment: @HåkenLid can you show me an example how it should be done?

Comment: There's no one size fits all solution. But you can find lots of suggestions by googling `cron in docker`. Tutorials and stack overflow questions. Typically docker containers are meant to run a single job. To orchestrate several services, you can use docker-compose. It's also possible to use supervisord to run several deamons in a single container.